# Create catalog for WPF and Silverlight from XAML

Tags: silverlight, module, prism, mef, catalog

I am developing application for WPF and Silverlight by ProjectLinker with PRISM and MEF modularity.
My modules are Class Library (in WPF) and Silverlight Class Library (in Silverlight).
Now I want to load modules in WPF or Silverlight by Catalog.xaml  from server.

Problem is:
- Silverlight cannot load DLL but only XAP
- WPF cannot load XAP but only DLL

How can I do that - developing by project linker (same code for both platforms), create modules, download from server and load to application?

I have in bootstrapper: 
On server WCF I have Catalog.xaml - I download it and...
`catalog = Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(stream);` - it works
But If I run application by the load module I have an error (I tried to load DLL to Silverlight).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on type of project. Project for silverlight must be as Silverlight application. So I changed type of silverlight project and now build for WPF is DLL and for silverlight is XAP. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link *from the PRISM website*: [Sharing Code Between Silverlight and WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921109%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

For the Module catalogs, you will either need to create separate XAML files, or use possibly use TT files to generate them from a common set of module names.

*As you need to carefully specify the dependencies for Silverlight to get the best start times, you might be better off maintaining separate files.*